# Unit Tests are always "successful" after adding OCMock

Tags: cocoa, unit-testing, frameworks, ocmock, sentestingkit

I would like to use OCMock in my Cocoa project's unit tests. I have downloaded the latest version of OCMock (2.0.1) and copied the *OCMock.framework* into my project's directory. In Xcode, I have added the framework to the unit test target's *link* phase. I have then added some code that uses OCMock's classes.

From then on out, all unit tests are reported as "successful" - green light, no errors or warnings. Even after introducing `STFail` calls, Xcode claims "Test succeeded". Placing a breakpoint in arbitrary test methods reveals that none of them are executed.

The issue persists if I comment out the code using OCMock, including the `import` directives.

The issue vanishes - i.e., the `STFails` start failing again - when I remove OCMock from the link phase.

This is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842417/unit-tests-always-successful) I've asked before, but not exactly the same: In this case, the info in the Log Navigator shows no errors. What could be causing this behavior? What can I do to diagnose the matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was [missing a *Copy Files* build phase](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=271&sid=f524a0ce592892cbfb8fb9ae421add1c) for the framework, which apparently may lead to [a variety of issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760435/adding-ocmock-causes-test-to-launch-main-app-instead-of-running-tests).

This works for me:

1. Add a *Copy Files* phase to the unit test target's build phases. I positioned it right before the *Run Script* phase, making it the second-to-last one.
2. Drag the *OCMock.framework* item from the project navigator onto the phase in order to add it; adding it using the `+` button doesn't work in Xcode 4.6 (maybe because frameworks are directories?).
3. Set the phase's destination to "Frameworks".
4. In the unit test target's build settings, look for *Runpath Search Paths* and add the entry `@loader_path/../Frameworks`.

This way, the unit test executable will be able to find the framework at runtime. Note that you can also use "Products Directory" as the destination of the *Copy Files* phase, in which case you can skip the fourth step.